# Show $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal $\leftrightarrow \alpha \neq 0$ and $\cup \alpha = \alpha$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, supremum-and-infimum

> $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal $\leftrightarrow \alpha \neq 0$ and $\cup \alpha = \alpha$

Sorry if this question has been asked already but I couldn't find it on this site.

I assume by definition of a limit ordinal you can state it does not equal $0$. As for showing $\cup \alpha = \alpha$, you have the fact that Sup($\alpha$) = $\cup \alpha$ but I don't really know where to go from there, especially if I want a concrete rigorous proof.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** If $\alpha=\beta+1$, show that $\bigcup\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: Are you basically showing $\beta \in \alpha$ so $\beta \subseteq \cup \alpha$ so $\cup \alpha \geq$ Sup($\alpha$) $... \cup \alpha = Sup(\alpha) = \beta$

Comment: If you show my hint, you get that if $\alpha$ is not a limit ordinal, then the condition fails;  and the proof (I'm hoping) will help you see why the second implication holds as well.

Comment: Yes by this it means it is a successor ordinal and therefore  not a limit ordinal. Therefore by deduction $\bigcup \alpha = \alpha$